# When using Order By it does not take the stock correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

the idea is that it takes the group by in descending order, but it doesn't do it

`SELECT * FROM dev_transacciones GROUP BY id_producto order by stock ASC`

Comment: `ASC` is ascending order. `DESC` is descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
    SELECT * FROM dev_transacciones GROUP BY id_producto order by stock DESC
```

**ASC** stands for Ascending, and **DESC** stands for Descending.

I recommend that you read through this site:

https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_order_by.php

In order to understand more about how these orders in SQL are generated.